# php issue when running on linux with dot slash filename format

Tags: linux, php

I have a script   (file1.php)in php in linux

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
 echo "hello world" ?>
```

when i run in linux (redhat @ bash shell)

```
>  php file1.php
```

it works. my php is in /usr/bin/php and its version is 5.3.3)

but when i run

```
./file1.php
```

it says

```
'./file1.php' not present.
```

my application requires this (`'./file1.php'`) model to work

on my other machine this file works with (`'./file1.php'`) model

why is it so , is there any way to fix this ..

- **/usr/bin/php -v  works well
- file permission (file1.php): -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root**

Comment: is the file executable, e.g. chmod 755? to use `./file.php`, it must be executable.

Comment: are you in the same directory as file1.php when you do this?

Comment: @Orangepill yes sure on the same directory

Comment: what did /usr/bin/php -v return

Comment: @Orangepill :
PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Feb 22 2013 02:51:11) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies

Comment: and `/usr/bin/php -q ./file.php` works without a hitch.. is the code above one you are testing with or a simplified version?

Answer (score 2):

You should indicate how your file should be executed. In bash, it's done using a **shebang**
Try adding this line add the very top of your php script:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php echo 'Hello world!';
```

This would tell bash to run `./file.php` as `php /fullpath/file.php`
More info http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)

Comment: removed -q from the shebang now it says 
-bash: ./file1.php: /usr/bin/php^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory , ## am on the same directory

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Try creating a file with the exact content I wrote above, make sure you set executing permissions `chmod +x file.php`, and run it as `./file.php`
Edit: That's bash indicating it can't find the php interpreter. Run `whereis php`, it will thell you where your php interpreter is. You should use that path. You said yours was on `/usr/bin/php` so running `/usr/bin/php --version` should work, and the code above should work.

Comment: created , it says 
Extension './file1.php' not present.

Comment: it's trying to load ./file1.php as an extension not as a script file. It's acting like it's calling /usr/bin/php -z file.php

Comment: type `alias` on the command line... see if there is any php alias set

Comment: I think @Orangepill may be on the right track. It's more of a *nix/bash config problem than a php one